# How do I find out what string the user tried to input into a integer function?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I get this program to work?
If the user inputs a letter or word into the input function, instead of an integer the program should print "this is not a number". But if the user inputs "stop" instead of the integer, the program is supposed to stop. My code looks like this:

```
try:
    inp = int(input("number:"))
    print(inp)
except:
    if inp == "I don't know":
        print("learn math")
    else:
        print("This is not a number!")
```

Comment: In what way(s) does it not work?  And what did you do to try and fix them?

Comment: Do the `input` and `int` as separate steps.

Comment: @MarkRansom Can you help me and write the code? Can't get it to work

Comment: @ScottHunter The program can't tell the difference between a specific word and a random letter/word as it is in a try except function.

Comment: My hint should have been enough for you - I'd hate to rob you of the experience of learning!  I'll leave you with one more, because you never assigned `input()` to a variable you don't have any way to see what string was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Taking input in one line and converting it to int in another line should work.

```
try:
    inp = input("number:")
    inp = int(inp)
    print(inp)
except:
    if inp == "I don't know":
        print("learn math")
    else:
        print("This is not a number!")
```

YW!

Comment: I hope `quit` here is meant as pseudo-code, because it doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
   string=input('enter values :')
   if string=='stop':
        break
   elif string=="I don't know":
       print('learn math')
   if string.isalpha:
       print('Not a number !')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.